# Firestore subscribe to topic structure, ways around the 1MB limit?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am attemping to create a subscription function in Android using Firestore.
If I have two collections such as:

```
Topics Collection
uid
field1
...
fieldN
userIds[]

Publications Collection
    uid
    field1
    ...
    fieldN
    topicIds[]
```

So when a subscriber wants to subscribe to a topic his uid is added to the userIds array, once you want to check to which topics the current user is subscribed you can just query if his id is in said array. Same logic goes for publications.

However. Considering the limit of a firestore doc is 1MB, this would also limit the amount of people who could possible subscribe to a topic as the uid of each sub is added to the arraylist. Is there any smart query or way around this limitation that would allow for more people to subscribe?

Comment: What is the max number of topics a user can subscribe? Basically how many UIDs would you like to add to the list?

Comment: 500-700 max topics max

Comment: If there are only 500-700, have you tried adding them all to a single document? In Android, you can use this [library](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document) to check the document size.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Would there be a code-wise way to add the "name" of those let's say 500 topics to a user document (in an array perhaps); and then somehow search for all documents containing the "names" in the array?

Comment: So you want to perform a query for each element that exists in the array? So if the array contains 500 names, do you want to perform 500 separate queries?

Answer (score 0):

The document size limit cannot ever be exceeded.  For unbounded lists of things, your only scalable option is to store each list item as a separate document.  Typically you would want to do this in a subcollection of the main document.  There is no limit to the number of documents that can be in a collection.

You could also try to spread the data across arrays in multiple documents, but you will just create a new set of problems to solve.

Comment: Could you provide a structure snippet as example of what you wrote above about "store each list item as a seperate document"? How would i fetch all publications from this topic when using this method for scaleability?

Comment: There's no document structure here.  Just create a subcollection and write each item as a document in that subcollection.  If you have another question, please post it separately.